# Как сделать автоматическое нажатие клавиши?

Tags: pascal

Как сделать автоматическое нажатие клавиши, например, сочетание клавиш <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>?

Comment: @илья золотойq, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы эмулировать нажатие клавиши на клавиатуре, надо в любой процедуре или функции написать такой код:

```
keybd_event(VK_LCONTROL, 0, 0, 0); //Нажатие левого Ctrl.
keybd_event(Ord('F'), 0, 0, 0); //Нажатие 'f'.

keybd_event(Ord('F'), 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0); //Отпускание 'f'.
keybd_event(VK_LCONTROL, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0); //Отпускание левого Ctrl.
```

Чтобы найти коды клавиш или какие-то подробности относительно происходящего, наберите в google: "delphi эмуляция нажатия клавиш".